# Can't check ASCII values of user-inputted characters in Tkinter

Tags: python, encoding, tkinter, character, ascii

I'm using Python 2 and Tkinter to create a graphical program. The program allows the user to input something and then click a button to check whether the input is fully numeric or not. I'm attempting to do this using a function that checks the ASCII value of every character in the input. However, it does not appear to be working correctly with user inputs in Tkinter, even though the input is stored as a string. The label above the input box will change, to reflect whether the input was identified as fully numeric or not. Even though the input is fully numeric, the label still changes to "Input is not numeric only.".

Here is my code:

```
#coding: iso-8859-1
from Tkinter import*
root = Tk()

def input_numeric(inpput):
    if len(inpput) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(inpput)):
            if inpput[i] < 48 or inpput[i] > 57:
                return False
        return True

def something():
    if input_numeric(inpput.get()) == False:
        labbel.configure(text = "Input is not numeric only.")
    else:
        labbel.configure(text = "Input is fully numeric!")

labbel = Label(root, text = "Type something: ")
labbel.pack()

inpput = StringVar()
typing_box = Entry(root, textvariable = inpput)
typing_box.pack(fill = BOTH)

click_button = Button(text = "Click this button", command = something)
click_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Python 1-length strings are not C `char`s.

Comment: try to insert `print ord(inpput[i])` into your for cycle to see what characters are you getting

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot that in Python you have to use the ord function to get the ASCII values. Now it works perfectly! :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "numeric"? Does `-12` count? `1.2`? What about Persian digits like `۱۲`? Or things like `½`? If you mean "can be interpreted as an `int` by Python", the easiest way to check that is to `try` to interpret it as an `int`. If you mean "is made up entirely of characters whose Unicode type is Nd", that's `isdigit`. If you mean "is made up entirely of ASCII digit characters, that's "ch in string.digits`. And so on.

Comment: I mean that the input only contains numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is solved, but I'd like to suggest a better way: use [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
#coding: iso-8859-1
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def something():
    if inpput.get().isdigit():
        labbel.configure(text = "Input is fully numeric!")
    else:
        labbel.configure(text = "Input is not numeric only.")

labbel = Label(root, text = "Type something: ")
labbel.pack()

inpput = StringVar()
typing_box = Entry(root, textvariable = inpput)
typing_box.pack(fill = BOTH)

click_button = Button(text = "Click this button", command = something)
click_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This works because `Tkinter.StringVar.get` returns a string object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is that you're comparing one-character strings to numbers. In Python 2.x, all numbers are less than all strings. (The exact rules for comparing values of different types is a bit complicated, but don't worry about that here.) In Python 3.x, comparing a number to a string just raises an exception.

To find out if the ASCII value of a one-character string is less than 48, you need to either use `ord` to convert the string to its 8-bit or Unicode codepoint, or use `chr` or `unichr` to convert 48 into a one-character string; if you do either of those, the comparison will work.

However, there's a much simpler way to do this.

First, why even use `48` and `57` in the first place? If you just write `inpput[i] < '0' or inpput[i] > '9'` it will work, and be more readable. (And that works just as well in C as in Python, by the way.) Or, even more simply, use a chained comparison, like `'0' <= inpput[i] <= '9'`.

But if you're really trying to check whether every character is an ASCII digit, Python has an even easier way. You can just check whether `inpput[i] in string.digits`.

Or, even simpler, you can just check the whole string at once, with `inpput.isdigit()`. But this does something different. It checks whether every character is a digit using the appropriate definition for your default character set (if it's a `str`) or for Unicode (if it's a `unicode`). For example, `u'۱۲'.isdigit()` is True, because both of those characters are digits. (They're Persian digits for `1` and `2`.) There are also characters that are "numeric", but not "digits", like `½`; `isdigit` will return False for those.

And that raises a larger question: What exactly are you trying to test here? Do you want "just ASCII digits"? Or "just digits"? Or "is something Python can interpret as an `int`"? There are many possible things "numeric" can mean, and there's an easy way to test each one of them; the important thing is deciding which one is the one you want.

For example, if your rule is "something Python can interpret as a non-negative `int`", the obvious rule is to call `int` on it, then check that it's non-negative:

```
def input_numeric(inpput):
    try:
        i = int(inpput)
        return i >= 0
    except ValueError:
        return False
```